# For the 'Wayward Wizard' companion what is a Talisman?

Tags: neverwinter

Been playing for about a week and finally got a Wayward Wizard as a companion. Cool.  I get that he can only use certain items when slots become available but there is one that is initially available as 'Talisman' and I can find nothing that goes into that location.

I've checked around the game forums but I must be the only person having the problem :(

What is it and what can go in it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talismans are Control Wizard items "Off-Hand, Talisman" for example I have one now that is: [image: Smiting Caster's Talisman].

Comment: Thanks, I must be going blind but I have NEVER found one as loot or seen one on the AH.  I'll poke around more.

Answer (score 0):

I struggles with this myself when I was leveling up my Ranger, they don't normally drop when you're not that class, but you can easily get cheap ones from item merchants, but even equipped to your companion they will stay red.